# How to remote debug two applications on the same WebSphere Liberty

Tags: java, websphere, remote-debugging, websphere-liberty

I have two applications Java 8 applications that exposes different typologies of services, but they rely on each other for some task. They are implemented in the same WebSphere Application Server on the remote server. 
However, since I don't have a license for it, if I need to debug something, I'm using WebSphere Liberty. So far, I only had configured the application A and I was trying to configure application B. My goal was to also set the remote debug options.

So far, I made this in my jvm.options

```
-Denv.target=local
-DSRV_CFG=C:\\myproperties\\application.properties
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

The two agentlib options have been issued, for me, by IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, which proposed me the following for a remote JVM execution

[image]

#### The Need

I need to have two applications, under the same WebSphere Liberty, because they share the same session.

#### The Problem

Though I know its 2022, I didn't have that much budget (nor time...) to remake the login process in order to not rely on a JSESSIONID as many front-ends rely on Application A, so I decided to develop Application B as a new .ear that was going to be deployed under the same WAS. 
In trying to simulate the remote debug connection scenario, where I have both applications up and running, I can't start WebSphere Liberty because of the following error

```
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
```

If I just try to remove one jdwp, and just try to boot the remote debug session from IntelliJ, it gives the following error

[image]

#### What I tried to do

I've tried to look on the internet for some solutions, specifically trying to understand if the same jdwp could be used to listen on two different ports and if WAS Liberty supported somehow remote debugging for two applications deployed under the same server. I happened to find [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/debugging-two-applications-same-time-fails-error-connection-refused) page by IBM itself, which states that this setup is not possible. 
But since this page is 4 years old, I was wondering if, after all this time, there's a chance somehow to do this and, if so, how.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I know the answer to your question but maybe I can help clear up some confusion.  It seems like the article you referenced https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/debugging-two-applications-same-time-fails-error-connection-refused might be confusing you.

From a more general tooling perspective when connecting the Java debugger from Eclipse or IntellJ to a WebSphere server (either WebSphere Liberty or traditional WebSphere Application Server), you are simply configuring a connection to the entire server JVM via a single port.  Within this server you can set breakpoints and debug within one application, two applications, or any number of applications.  You can even debug through the server runtime code in the same debugger connection (this will be easier to set up if you're using the fully open source Open Liberty, but the point is that the debugger will allow you to work with any relevant application or runtime source running in that server JVM).

Therefore you would expect a jvm.options to have only one JVM option for configuring the remote debugger, e.g. to look more like:

> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777

regardless of the number of applications you're debugging.

The source of the confusion might be, however, the fact that RAD, with its WebSphere-specific development tool (not just a general Java debugger tool), provides more of an application-centric point of view for debugging an app developed in the IDE workspace, deployed to a WebSphere server managed by the IDE.   It is from this IDE-centric view that you might not be able to debug two applications at once.

By the way I'm not an expert in the RAD tool, so I don't mean to vouch for that specific information in that article, but regardless, I hope this helps.